# Setting a Firemonkey control OnMouseMove method

Tags: c++, event-handling, firemonkey, c++builder-xe7, tgrid

I have a custom control for which I am trying to define an OnMouseMoveFunction.  Essentially, the control functions as a search bar, and is made up of an edit box with a child custom `TGrid` control for displaying results.  I am handling several mouse events for the `TGrid` already, however when trying to implement OnMouseMove I am getting the following error when I try to set the `TGrid` OnMouseMove method:

`E2034 Cannot convert 'void (_fastcall * (_closure )(TMouseMoveEvent))(TMouseMoveEvent)' to 'TMouseMoveEvent'`

Here is the piece of the header file where the function is defined:

`void __fastcall GridMouseMove( TMouseMoveEvent * MouseEvent );`

Here is the actual function inside the control's CPP file:

```
void __fastcall TFmSearchBar::GridMouseMove( TMouseMoveEvent * MouseEvent )
{
    //handle event here
}
```

Up to this point everything will compile just fine.  However, when I go to assign the `TGrid`'s OnMouseMoveEvent handler to the method I have assigned, I get the error.

```
void __fastcall TFmSearchBar::SetGridProperties()
{
    FGrid->OnKeyDown  = GridKeyDown;
    FGrid->OnClick = GridClick;
    FGrid->OnMouseEnter = GridMouseEnter;
    FGrid->OnMouseLeave = GridMouseLeave;
    FGrid->OnMouseMove = GridMouseMove; //This line causes the error
}
```

What am I missing that is causing this not to build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use declarations, generated by IDE for TGrid.

Header:

```
void __fastcall GridMouseMove(TObject *Sender, TShiftState Shift, float X, float Y);
```

Implementation from cpp:

```
void __fastcall TFmSearchBar::GridMouseMove(TObject *Sender, TShiftState Shift, float X,
          float Y)
{
    ShowMessage("123");
}
```

Assignment (the same):

```
void __fastcall TFmSearchBar::SetGridProperties()
{
    ...
    FGrid->OnMouseMove = GridMouseMove; //This line causes the error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The native `TMouseMoveEvent` type is *already* a pointer type, so remove the `*` from your declarations:

```
void __fastcall GridMouseMove( TMouseMoveEvent MouseEvent );
```

```
void __fastcall TFmSearchBar::GridMouseMove( TMouseMoveEvent MouseEvent )
{
    //handle event here
}
```